# Designing a second order HPF with a high gain common-source

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, amplifier, high-pass-filter

I have a High gain (A = 22k) Common-Source circuit, and I was wondering If I can make a second order HPF like this circuit:

[image]

My circuit is just an NMOS with an input at the gate, output at the Drain, and I'm assuming it has 22k gain, (So approximately infinity)

is a second-order-HPF possible in some way with a regular High gain Common-source? I can't figure out the connections

My `theoretical` circuit (5V and not 1V VDD, sorry):

[image]

thank you!

Comment: why not N&P MOS

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 oh I'm not familliar I'll read about it now

Comment: how have you managed to measure a gain of 22k with one fet

Comment: CMOS 4000 series buffered inverters had a fair amount of gain with 3 stages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't design a reasonable 2nd order HPF with 1 Nch  FET.

Unreasonable might be;

1. gain > 10k
2. Resistors that are < 10 Rd as source impedance must be low for multiple feedback filters or > 33 M.
3. Caps too big or too small <= Cin
4. Freq. too high for the amplifier
5. not properly DC biased just above Vt.

[here's a quick n dirty ~750kHz HPF with a gain of ~280 at 1MHz](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgbALCBMCmC0AOEAGAdARgOwcYsAnNAKyLSIEDM5Y4KIxDlDCGGAUAEowrLUgYw9fvXoR60UalRpi7AE48%200JQIwr6GFNpTsAxjGK0MEKNU1FpxNGATItNyqTDEILsINfN02jooLGQiABApb0Rjq6APIg5qEqlIhQGGGo7ADuqti0ksi5aZn5JlAkxqZpAGYCQYISvNVSGLIC7AAOsZLxHRLiAiBQuoX1xVnqMBkNk2wqtQUdaioh03PLs0tBuor8y9sb4Ig6%20vOz8LuNCAQC6GCUWNDQBMRYYM9a0ANovuwA5sHGliF7gM0gZ1sIZnsMBcQPACJ8qBQIMQCFgkUZBDIvth6KcITiDlMrjoGJFtJjtIwfChKD9VPl6e9pIM-gtRhoFCzlmDpJRKKSOXEUip6fVNKTtOwAPb9Qy0TTkFAaTCIVzEUokLCog4QLDklAYaQcIA)

- with a log sweep 10k to 5Meg in 3ms unidirectional. gm=43, Zin = 200 ohms

[image]

Adjust Rg ratio for desired Vd voltage for 50% roughly of Vdd and use a low impedance source or buffered source 50 ohm or less.